# Pattern to handle duplicate primary keys in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using the npm sequelize library for storage with MySQL. Primary key is the Task id, generated using shortid library.

What is a good Javascript pattern to handle repeated ids, in the unlikely event that shortid gives me a duplicate key? I'm thinking of returning false when the duplicate key error is caught, and having a outer while loop to re-attempt the task creation again (with a newly generated id).

This is quite an ugly solution, so are there better ways to do this?

```
        Task.create({
            id: shortid.generate(),
            content: task.content,
            deadline: task.deadline
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('repeated id');
            return false;
        }).then(function() {
            console.log('yay ok');
            return true;
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Only way to fix this is to actually generate new ID if old one was repeated. To represent this in the code you can change the `create` into a recursive function like so :

```
function createTask(task){
  Task.create({
            id: shortid.generate(),
            content: task.content,
            deadline: task.deadline
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('repeated id');
            createTask(task);  // this will keep calling itself until it successfully creates the record with unique id
            return false;
        }).then(function() {
            console.log('yay ok');
            return true;
        });
}

// now creating the task will look like: 
createTask(task);
```

This definitely is a optimistic recursive function  assuming only error you get is from repeated IDs, and that your generator will eventually generate unique ID. If either of those assumptions are false you "may" get stuck loop, in which case you will have to implements those checks and break the recursion conditionally.